# Meaning of symbols

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, symbolic-computation

What does these symbols "∔" and "∸" in mathematics means?
Example of the sentences for ∔:
A linear manifold X of the inner product space (X,[·,·]) is a direct summand of X^0 (i.e. X = L∔X^0 for some linear manifold L in X) if and only if it is maximal nondegenerate.
Example of the sentences for ∸:
Write a formal register machine that computes the function f(x,y)=2x ∸ 2y.

Comment: New for me too!

Comment: It's not very standard notation, so I would hope that those who use the notation define it.

Comment: Where have you found these? If possible post a link.

Comment: @lhf it from my past exam papers and my professor notes.

Answer (score 1):

From [this](http://cogprints.org/2875/1/ClassRecTheory0.pdf) document: "the binary operator ∸ is defined by x∸y = x – y if x > y, and 0 otherwise"

From [this](https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/handle/10012/3698/Rob_thesis_final.pdf?sequence=1) document: "Here, ∔ denotes the direct sum of two linearly independent linear manifolds, see the next subsection for a more detailed explanation." This is on page 45.